# C# Google Cloud Srorage Api - Objects.Get Response

Tags: c#, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I've recently started using Google Cloud Storage within my .NET project.. And due to project's purpose, application makes get/insert API calls very frequently, like maybe 20-100 times in a second..

Currently, this is how I query an object from Google Storage:

```
using (StorageService service = getGoogleStorageService())
{
   return service.Objects.Get(bucketName, cloudKey).Execute();
}
```

I have two concerns that I couldn't find any clear answers on API examples.

First one; I generate a `cloudKey` on the run-time for every domain object I find in my local database, and then I need to check if there are any files with this key on the google storage. Since I couldn't find any API method like `"Exists()"`, I have to use the same `"Get()"` method as above. And API returns an `Exception` with `404 (Not Found)` response if it doesn't exists. So, I have to parse this 404 Error and assume the file doesn't exist. I wonder if there are any better practice to check if a file exists on the storage, because to me this solution doesn't seem to be a good one and may slow down the application with so many requests going on.

Second one; since my main concern here is the bandwidth and getting a fast response from API, I wonder if this `.Excute()` method also downloads the file content in the response or not. In both case if it downloads or if it doesn't download the file content, is there still any way to reduce the response size when my goal is only querying the file existence.

--

Comment: execute on Objects.get returns an object Resource https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource  Not sure what your quota limit is.   You might want to try doing an objects.list first then you will know if its there or not before doing a full get.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list